# Jacoco report for Cucumber Test

Tags: cucumber, integration, code-coverage, jacoco

Seeking some suggestions on an issue that I am facing while trying to generate the jacoco code coverage report for Cucumber tests.

Below is the steps that I had followed:
1. placed the org.jacoco.agent-0.8.2-runtime.jar in my local machine

2. Added the agent to JVM option of the cucumber runner configuration, refer the screen shot below:
   [cucmberRunnerConfiguration SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2kVd.jpg)
3. start the application in local ( Spring boot micro service application)
4. Execute the BDD tests. the .exec file is generated.
5. using the .exec file, a gradle task was added in the build.gradle to generate the report. below is the task definition:

   apply plugin: 'java'

apply plugin: 'maven'

apply plugin: 'jacoco'

jacoco {

toolVersion = "0.8.2"

reportsDir = file("$buildDir/jacocoHtml")

}

task generateJacocoUTReport(type: JacocoReport, group: "rpac") {

dependsOn allprojects.test

additionalSourceDirs = files(subprojects.sourceSets.main.allSource.srcDirs)

sourceDirectories = files(subprojects.sourceSets.main.allSource.srcDirs)

classDirectories = files(subprojects.sourceSets.main.output)

executionData file("$buildDir/resources/bddTest.exec")

reports {

```
xml.enabled = false

csv.enabled = false

html.destination file("$buildDir/jacoco/html")
```

}

afterEvaluate {

```
classDirectories = files(classDirectories.files.collect {

  fileTree(dir: it, exclude: [

          //list of files or packages to be exdluded

          '**/web/*',

          '**/schemas/*',

          '**/pipeline/*',

          '**/gradle/*',

          '**/config/*',

          '**/api/*'

  ])

})
```

}

}

Result : I am able to generate the jacoco report successfully.

Issue : the report looks very weird, there is no details about the classes, no coverage %, it all shows 0. please refer the below image attached.

[jacoco report by task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kccS.png)

tried many options and I really could not figure out what is the root cause.
Any suggestion or a better solution would be really appreciated.

Thanks
Balesh

Comment: You have too many components involved here. Cucumber, Spring, IDEA, the Cucumber IDEA plugin, Gradle, ect. Try to reduce the problem first and then build back up. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: my applicaion is a gradle based application and those projects are gradle specific.